# Change the value of a variable inside a loop

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to change the value of the variable declared outside the loop within a loop. But, even when changing hit inside the loop, it keeps the initial value outside the loop.

```
{% set foo = False %}

{% for item in items %}
  {% set foo = True %}
  {% if foo %} Ok(1)! {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if foo %} Ok(2)! {% endif %}
```

This renders:

```
Ok(1)!
```

So the only (bad) solution I have found so far was this:

```
{% set foo = [] %}

{% for item in items %}
  {% if foo.append(True) %} {% endif %}
  {% if foo %} Ok(1)! {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if foo %} Ok(2)! {% endif %}
```

This renders:

```
Ok(1)!
Ok(2)!
```

But, it's is very ugly! Is there another more elegant solution?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way. Perhaps you could restructure the code so that you don't need to set the variable.

Comment: +1 for the question, as it became answer for me :)

Comment: @Shankar Cabus: great question. This should probably be classified under `Jinja Annoyances`

Comment: I think this is question is duplicated in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537439/how-to-increment-a-variable-on-a-for-loop-in-jinja-template
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block/4880398#4880398
(just starting, can't flag the question) You can use Pashka's approach, and add `jinja2.ext.do` to clean it a little bit

Comment: I found this code to be the only way to workaround construct that I was unable to use in salt+jinja: somelist|map(format)|join

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try also dictionary-based approach. It seems to be less ugly.

```
{% set vars = {'foo': False} %}

{% for item in items %}
  {% if vars.update({'foo': True}) %} {% endif %}
  {% if vars.foo %} Ok(1)! {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if vars.foo %} Ok(2)! {% endif %}
```

This also renders:

```
Ok(1)!
Ok(2)!
```

Comment: Still ugly, but it works. I'm quite surprised there is no Pythonic way of doing this with jinja2.

Comment: Definitely a bit cleaner especially if you need more than one variable

Comment: TLDR, does `set vars` just plain not work in a for loop?

Comment: @kramer65: Solutions appear to be in the works: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/684; https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/676

Comment: @ThorSummoner seems like it. I have been hearing a lot of people praise python. They are just cooking with water as well.

Comment: Doesn't work in Askama 2023.

Comment: @ThorSummoner I haven't checked intensively, but it seems like setting variables inside a loop overshadows the outside loop variable. Once the scopus of the new variable is left, the variable name refers to the old variable again. Weird.

Answer (score 94):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#for):

> Please note that assignments in loops will be cleared at the end of
> the iteration and cannot outlive the loop scope.

but as of version 2.10 you can use [namespaces](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-globals.namespace):

```
{% set ns = namespace(foo=false) %}      
{% for item in items %}
  {% set ns.foo = True %}
  {% if ns.foo %} Ok(1)! {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if ns.foo %} Ok(2)! {% endif %}
```

Comment: Where you say `namespace(foo=false)` is the lowercase f in False a jinja2 colloquialism or did you mean False, as python requires for boolean values?

Comment: the lowercase false is part of jinja's convention:  " `The special constants true, false, and none are indeed lowercase. Because that caused confusion in the past, (True used to expand to an undefined variable that was considered false), all three can now also be written in title case (True, False, and None). However, for consistency, (all Jinja identifiers are lowercase) you should use the lowercase versions.`"

Comment: After trying for hours I thankfully found this answer! This works in Home Assistant templates.

Comment: Source: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/684

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to clean up the template code

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ set_foo_is_true(local_vars) }}
  {% if local_vars.foo %} Ok(1)! {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if local_vars.foo %} Ok(2)! {% endif %}
```

And in the server code use

```
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
#---------------------------------------------
local_vars = { 'foo': False }
def set_foo_is_true(local_vars):
  local_vars['foo'] = True
  return ''
env.globals['set_foo_is_true'] = set_foo_is_true    
#---------------------------------------------
return env.get_template('template.html').render(items=items, local_vars=local_vars)
```

This could be generalized to the following

```
{{ set_local_var(local_vars, "foo", False) }}
{% for item in items %}
  {{ set_local_var(local_vars, "foo", True) }}
  {% if local_vars.foo %} Ok(1)! {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if local_vars.foo %} Ok(2)! {% endif %}
```

And in the server code use

```
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
#---------------------------------------------
local_vars = { 'foo': False }
def set_local_var(local_vars, name, value):
  local_vars[name] = value
  return ''
env.globals['set_local_var'] = set_local_var
#---------------------------------------------
return env.get_template('template.html').render(items=items, local_vars=local_vars)
```