# Jinja2 change variable inside a loop

Tags: python, jinja2

```
{% set foo = 200 %}

 {% for item in items %}
   {% set foo = 100 %}
   {{ foo  }}
 {% endfor %}

{{foo}}
```

Output
100
200

foo outside of my Loop should be 100
how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try also dictionary-based approach. It seems to be less ugly.

```
{% set vars = {'foo': False} %}

{% for item in items %}   {% if vars.update({'foo': True}) %} {% endif %}   
{% if vars.foo %} Ok(1)! {% endif %} {% endfor %}

{% if vars.foo %} Ok(2)! {% endif %}
```

This also renders:

```
Ok(1)!
Ok(2)!
```

Comment: If you're going to copy answers word for word, at least have the decency of [linking to the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486393/jinja2-change-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-loop)

Comment: I didn't get it from stackoverflow - it was from another site.