# Accessing loop variable outside loop in Jinja2

Tags: for-loop, jinja2, ansible-2.x

We are writing a `for` loop in Jinja2, which will keep on concatenating the list variable to a string until the end of the list.We are storing the string to a variable. After the loop completes, we want to print the variable.

The code to perform that is as follows

```
{% set HOSTLIST = groups['master'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address'])| list %}
{% set TEST = "spark://" %}
{% for host in HOSTLIST %}
     {% set sample = TEST + host  %}
     {% set TEST = sample+',' %}
{% endfor %}

{{ TEST }}
```

Can anybody point me, where we are doing a mistake.

Our output is as follows:

```
 spark://
```

But the expected output should be like:

```
 spark://192.168.49.111:7077,192.168.49.112:7077,
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use it like this?

```
spark://{{ groups['master'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | map('regex_replace','$',':7077') | list | join(',') }}
```

Your original request to modify outer-scope variable inside a loop is solved only with jumping through some hoops, see [Jinja2: Change the value of a variable inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486393/jinja2-change-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-loop).

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer, but I want to add one more condition,
I want the output as spark://10.0.2.124:7077,10.0.2.156:7077
Here the port number will be passed as variable `PORT`

Comment: see modified answer

Comment: I donot want to hardcode the port, the port should be passed as variable in ansible.

Comment: I beg you pardon, but I wouldn't fix my answer for your every need. I gave you a direction of thinking, you may tweak it any way - add variables instead of predefined strings, etc...

Comment: sorry for bugging you, but I was not expecting you to bug me, I wanted the way you want to pass the `:7077` as variable into the map function or to the join.

Comment: just type your var name instead of `':7077'`.

Comment: Thanks!! It solved my issue, and got me a good solution, but I want to know how to access the loop variable outside the loop.

Comment: Added link to my answer.