# Why is my Jinja counter not incrementing in my HTML table?

Tags: html, jinja2, counter

I have the following html code:

```
     <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Counter</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>

                {% set count = 1 %}
                {% for i in range(5) %}

                    <td>{{ count }}</td>

                {% set count = count + 1 %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I want to create a table that displays one number in each column. These numbers should be incremented using this loop. However, it shows only the number 1 in each column like this:

```
Counter
1   1   1   1   1
```

To me, it seems as if this error could only occour, if I set the count variable as 1 INSIDE the for loop, which I didn't do. Can someone help me out? I have been trying to fix this for hours

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76235390/trying-to-increment-counter-in-jinja2/76235591#76235591?

Comment: This said, in this case you should better do `<td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>` or `<td>{{ loop.index }}</td>`