# How to declare a variable in jinja2 outside of a for and increment the value to use it outside of the for?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, jinja2

I am trying to increment my amount variable through a for but only within the for does the increment.
I already printed my quantity variable inside the for and it increments but when I use it outside of the for it doesn't increment, I can't find any solution.

this is my code:

```
{% set cantidad = 0 %}
{% for count in allRoutes["outbound"]["Colombia"] %}
 {% if count.start_point == routeTable[0] %}
    {% set cantidad = cantidad + 1 %}
     {{cantidad}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{cantidad}}
```

I'm looking to increment and use my quantity variable outside of the for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the value of a variable inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486393/change-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-loop)