# Jinja2 template, variable resets in the loop

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to iterate over the array to change colours of my tags:

```
{% set colors = ["red", "green", "brown"] %}
            {% set idx = 0 %}
            {% for slug in page.tags %}
                before: {{ idx }}
                <a href="projects/{{ slug|lower }}" class="tag tag--{{ colors[idx] }}">{{ slug }}</a>
                {% set idx = (idx + 1) % 3 %}
                after: {{ idx }}
            {% endfor %}
```

I added the `before: {{ idx }}` and `after: {{ idx }}` lines for debugging. They clearly show, that before is idx = 0, after it is correctly changed to idx = 1, but then it resets to 0 again. It doesn't retain the values when iterating in `for` loop. Why is that? How to do it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the value of a variable inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486393/change-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-loop)

Comment: Yep, the "update" did the trick. Thank you!