# jinja template variable assignment scope

Tags: python, scope, jinja2

Given the following Jinja snippet

```
        {% set sep='' %}                
        {% for stamp in stamp_list -%}
            {%- for heartbeat in heartbeat_list -%}
                {%- if heartbeat.name == site.name and heartbeat.stamp == stamp.stamp -%}
                    {{- heartbeat.sc_time -}}
                    {{- sep -}}
                    {% set sep=',' %}
                                            [PROOF for new value {{ sep }}]
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endfor %}
```

Look at the sep variable (short for separator) I want to separate the sc_time with comma's.. like 3.13,2.5,1.33,...

So I introduce the var sep, which I change in the inner if.. Reading the Ninja I see nothing about scope inside for loops or if's and YES I can actually use and change the sep var... in this sample the line

```
             {% set sep=',' %}
```

is executed and the following line

```
             [PROOF ...
```

actually results in displaying the , BUT, the next time

```
             {{- sep -}}
```

just renders again as an empty var. What am I missing / not understanding here....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Jinja variable's scope extend beyond in an inner block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the scope if the variable. The `sep` variable inside you for loops is considered to be another variable than the variable you initialize at the top.

The same question and some answers are provided here:
[Can a Jinja variable's scope extend beyond in an inner block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block)