# set value command in jinja2 works in some cases and not in some

Tags: jinja2

The following code displays different values of x in different months. Set command of jinja2 works for flag,x but not for total. Why?

```
    {% set flag = 1 %}
    {% set total = 0 %}
    {% for date in dates %} //dates is some array
        {% if flag == 1 %}
            {{x}}
            {% set flag= 0 %} // I have used 1+1 also that too works
        {% elif "Jul" in date %}
            {% set x = x*3 %}
            {% if x % 10!=0 %}
                {% set x = x - x % 10 %}
                {% set total = total + x %}
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {{x}}
            {% set total = total + x %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{total}}
```

Comment: Is the problem that final `{{total}}` outputs 0? If so, it is because assignments inside for-loop doesn't affects on variables outisde that loop. See also that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726396/jinja-template-variable-assignment-scope

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block) too.

Comment: Flag is also inside for loop and it runs only once and its value changes to 0 then why is it different for total?

Comment: If I add {{flag}} after total it prints 0 and not 1. So either both flag and total should work or neither should work. I cannot understand. Please help!!

Comment: What value has `x`? Are you sure is not 0?

Comment: Yes its working perfectly fine. I can show you the original code but its too lengthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too complex computational logic in the *template*: it is better to move that logic(or its part) into *data-provider* component.

For example, in the data-provider component you can compute `x` for every `data` and place result into `data.x`. Then `{{dates|sum(attribute='x')}}` will display total value.

Comment: I think this will work can u provide any link that can elaborate how to use the following concept before I mark ur answer as chosen. plz

Comment: @TarunTrikha: About `sum` filter you can read its description at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters. As for "template should contain minimum logic" concept - it is common concept for most template engines. See, e.g. this FAQ: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates.