# Jinja2: local/global variable

Tags: flask, jinja2

```
{% set disabled = '' %}
{% for voter in record.voters %}
    {% if user == voter %}
        {% set disabled = 'disabled' %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ disabled }}  # outputs: 'disabled'
{% endfor %}
{{ disabled }}  # outputs: ''
```

I have that template in Jinja2.
What I need is 'disabled' variable to be visible outside 'for' loop.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to move the logic that sets the `disabled` variable to your view function and send it down to the template ready to be used. Mixing application logic with presentation is not a good idea, templates should receive the data as digested as possible.

That said, there is an ugly hack that makes what you want possible, shown in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block).

The solution involves enabling the `do` extension for Jinja2 and using it to modify a global array. To enable the extension use:

```
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.do')
```

Here is the solution adapted to your example:

```
{% set disabled = [] %}
{% for voter in record.voters %}
    {% if user == voter %}
        {% do disabled.append(1) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if disabled %}
    disabled
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thx. I already revised my code and did like you suggested at first.

Answer (score 13):

You can use an array/dict like Miguel suggests, but you do not need the do extension per se; you can set a dummy var. I use the following:

```
{% set glob={} %}
```

at the top, and then in my code:

```
{% set _ = glob.update({'disabled':True}) %}
```

The _ variables is just a dummy, you don't use it afterwards.

Comment: perfect, a bit hacky but that's all I needed 

Answer (score 7):

As of version 2.10 more complex use cases can be handled using namespace objects which allow propagating of changes across scopes:

```
{% set ns = namespace(found=false) %}
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.check_something() %}
        {% set ns.found = true %}
    {% endif %}
    * {{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
Found item having something: {{ ns.found }}
```

Comment: I can directly set ns.found=false as in
{% set ns.found = false %}

Answer (score 1):

By default blocks may not access variables from outer scopes, you can override this by using the `scoped` modifier like so:

```
{% for item in list scoped %}
{% endfor %}
```

See: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope

Comment: @c00p3r.web in that case I suggest opening an issue for jinja2 as that seems like functionality that would be desired: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/issues

Comment: This is a good solution, sadly it does only work in nested blocks/loops.

Answer (score 0):

I realise I'm answering to an old thread. However, I started using Jinja recently and ran into a similar problem: I needed to count the amount of printed rows in nested cycles. My solution was wrapping a counter variable in a class and passing an instance to the template. Similarly, you can use a wrapper class, like so

```
class VoterStatus(object):
    def __init__(self, status='active'):
        self._status = status

    def set_disabled(self):
        self._status = 'disabled'

    def __str__(self):
        return self._status
```

Modify your template accordingly

```
{% for voter in record.voters %}
    {% if user == voter %}
        {% status.set_disabled() %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ status }}  # outputs: 'disabled'
{% endfor %}
```

Pass a Status class instance to the template for rendering:

```
tmplt.render(status=VoterStatus(), ...)
```

...and Bob's your uncle.