# Scope of variable in jinja2 template

Tags: scope, conditional-statements, jinja2

I am writing  jinja2 template based application. I am trying to write a logic to set variable.

```
{% set last_item = none %}
{% for u in users %}
  {% if not u.username == user.username%}
    {% if  g.user.is_bestfriend(u) %}
      {% set last_item = 'true' %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{last_item}}
```

but after `{% endfor %}`, `last_item` value is again set to none, instead of true. Is there any way to set it to true in jinja2 template?

Comment: Check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block

Answer (score 6):

Since version 2.10 you can do this using a namespace variable, set before entering the scope:

```
{% set ns = namespace(found=false) %}
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.check_something() %}
        {% set ns.found = true %}
    {% endif %}
    * {{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
Found item having something: {{ ns.found }}
```

See also the documentation: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments

Answer (score 1):

Due to scoping rules in jinja2, you cannot access a variable outside the scope that it was set in. Sorry :(