# How to set/get variable in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, conditional-statements

I can't understand, why this code is not work:

```
{% set t_c = 'param_1' %}
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control " required>
                            <option></option>
                            {% for c in categories %}
                                {% if c.id|string == org.category.id %}
                                    {% set t_c = 'param9' %}
                                    <option value="{{ c.id }}" selected>{{ c.name }} </option>
                                {% else %}
                                    <option value="{{ c.id }}">{{ c.name }} </option>
                                {% endif %}                          
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
  <input id="category_h" name="category_h" type="hidden" value="{{ t_c }}">
```

Why **t_c** in last line is 'param_1', when condition  {% if c.id|string == org.category.id %} is true?

Thanks.

UPDATE

I have fast solution on JavaScript with jQuery+Select2 like:

```
var   category = $("#category"),
        category_h = $("#category_h");

 category.select2();
 category_h.val(category.find("option:selected").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

`t_c = 'param9'` is [local to the scope of the `for` loop](http://svn.python.org/projects/external/Jinja-1.2/docs/src/scopes.txt)

There are [workarounds to extend beyond inner block scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block)