# Jinja2 Frame Variables in Global Function

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a global function `test`

```
from jinja2.utils import contextfunction

@contextfunction
def test(context):
    context.get_all()
```

And in my test I'm calling it like this...

```
{% set i = 0 %}
{% for j in range(0, 10) %}
   {% set k = 0 %}
   {{ test() }}
{% endfor %}
```

The only variable that end up in the `context` in `test` is `i`.  `j` and `k` are "unreadable".  Is there any way to access them other than passing them into `test(j, k)`

Comment: are you importing with context in the template? (eg.: 
{% from 'admin/lib.html' import render_form, render_field, render_form_fields with context %} )

Comment: For sake of this example, there is no import.  `render` is called on the compiled template and `test()` is added to the `env['globals']`

Comment: You have to pass j, k to the function. Those variables are local to the for block and not available to the global context. j is self-explanatory; k is local because [`{% set %}` doesn't assign to the global context](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/164).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [github issue with a similar concern](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/164), the variables you have defined as `j` and `k` are set locally, and not globally. The function you are attempting to call will not recognize the variable `k` unless you pass it to the function. This is documented behavior.

Related stackoverflow questions:

[Can a Jinja variable's scope extend beyond in an inner block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block)

[Jinja2: Change the value of a variable inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486393/jinja2-change-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-loop)

Comment: This was my conclusion as well.  Good to have a sanity check. Seems strange you can't access the local block.