# Finding the sum of numbers in jinja2 template using flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I am learning flask and tried to create a web app that accepts a student's name and marks, finds the total of all the marks and display things in a table. But the total always gets displayed as `0`.

The code is given below

mark_total.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route('/')
def student():
        return render_template('student.html')

@app.route('/result', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                result = request.form
                return render_template('result.html', result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', debug = True)
```

student.html:

```
        <form action = "/result" method = "POST">
                <p>Name <input type = "text" name = "Name" /></p>
                <p>Physics <input type = "text" name = "Physics" /></p>
                <p>Chemistry <input type = "text" name = "chemistry" /></p>
                <p>Maths <input type ="text" name = "Mathematics" /></p>
                <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

result.html:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Results</title>
        </head>

        <body>
                <h1>{{result["Name"]}}'s results</h1>
                {% set total = 0 %}
                <table border = 1>
                {% for key, val in result.iteritems() %}
                        {% if key != 'Name' %}
                                {% set total = total|int + val|int %}
                                <tr>
                                        <td>{{ key }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ val }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ total }}</td>
                                </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>{{total}}</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

The html source of the output is as follows:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Results</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>ABC's results</h1>
  <table border = 1>
   <tr>
    <td>Mathematics</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>chemistry</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Physics</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>0</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me understand how to solve this?

Comment: Do you really have to do the calculations in the template? Why not calculate this in `mark_total.py` and pass the result to the template?

Comment: Yes. I tried doing the changes in the python and it worked. I wanted to try it with templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `total` defined inside the loop is not the same `total` defined (and accessed) outside of loop. This is what local scopes do.

You can overcome this by using a hack like this (adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860373/3025981) answer).

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Results</title>
        </head>

        <body>
                <h1>{{result["Name"]}}'s results</h1>
                {% set total = [0] %}
                <table border = 1>
                {% for key, val in result.iteritems() %}
                        {% if key != 'Name' %}
                                {% set _ = total.append(total.pop() + val|int) %}
                                <tr>
                                        <td>{{ key }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ val }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ total[0] }}</td>
                                </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>{{ total[0] }}</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

But I'm really not sure that it is a good idea to do such things in a template. The main idea of templates is to separate the logic (like counting the totals) and the representation, and this is a violation of this principle.

Comment: Thanks Ilya for not only answering the question but for suggesting the right approach too.

Answer (score 3):

When you change variable value inside a loop does not effect outside of the loop except a dict:

```
{% set total = {'value': 0} %}
...
    {% if total.update({"value": c|int + total.value|int }) %} {% endif %}
...
    {{total.value}}
```

Comment: Not only a dict. Actually, any mutable object will work.