# Concatenate strings in Jinja?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to concatenate strings in a state, and I'm not having much luck.  I've seen the posts that suggest using (|join), but all my strings are not in a single dictionary.  Here's my code:

```
sshd_content:
  file.line:
{% set admin_groups = '' %}
{% for app in grains['application_groups'] %}
{% for group in pillar['admin_users'][app]['members'] %}
{% set admin_groups = admin_groups ~ ' ' ~ group ~ '@mydomain.com' %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - match: AllowGroups wheel fred
    - mode: replace
    - content: AllowGroups wheel fred bob {{ admin_groups }}
```

I've tried using + instead of ~ without luck, too.

What am I doing wrong?

This state works fine:

```
sudoers_asmgroups_content:
  file.append:
    - name: /etc/sudoers.d/mygroups
    - text:
{% for app in grains['application_groups'] %}
  {% for group in pillar['admin_users'][app]['members'] %}
      - '%{{ group }}@mydomain.com ALL=(ALL) ALL'
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How does the result look like? Any errors in the master/minion logs?

Comment: There aren't any errors in /var/log/salt/minion on the target, nor in /var/log/salt/master on the master.  {{ admin_groups }} is empty.

Comment: What's interesting, though, is the state immediately above this one works fine.

`
sudoers_asmgroups_content:
  file.append:
    - name: /etc/sudoers.d/mygroups
    - text:
{% for app in grains['application_groups'] %}
{% for group in pillar['admin_users'][app]['members'] %}
      - '%{{ group }}@mydomain.com  ALL=(ALL)       ALL'
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
`

Comment: I've added it to your question, is the formatting of the added snippet the same as in your state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a viable solution by modifying the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870346/can-a-jinja-variables-scope-extend-beyond-in-an-inner-block).

It appears to be a scoping issue with the admin_groups variable.  Not sure why append works, but I'm not going to argue.

For the example in the OP above, here is the code:

```
sshd_content:
  file.line:
{% set admin_groups = [] %}
{% for app in grains['application_groups'] %}
{% for group in pillar['admin_users'][app]['members'] %}
{% do admin_groups.append(group) %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - match: AllowGroups wheel myadmin
    - mode: replace
    - content: AllowGroups wheel fred bob {{ admin_groups|join('@mydomain.com ') }}@mydomain.com 
{% endif %}
```

Need to add the second @domain.com since the items are AD group names, and join only adds the separator when there is another value.

Comment: Can't you just skip whole the loop in this case and just do `{{ pillar['admin_users'][app]['members']|join('@mydomain.com ') }}@mydomain.com`